# Bash READ prompt being able to tab and interact like a SHELL prompt

Tags: bash

I am developing a simple script which interactively asks the user folder paths to analyze.

```
read -p 'Provide the folder to analyze: ' newFolderToAnalyze
```

The problem or misbehaviour is that `read -p '...'` can't interact with the user shell environment, I can't just write `/home/` and then tab to **autocomplete**,

Is there any way using shell scripts to ask for something to the users but still using all the functions the shell prompt has to offer?

It seems like when the scripts enters that `read -p '..'` line, all the powerful functions from the interpreter vanishes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just use `read  -e -p 'Provide the folder to analyze: ' newFolderToAnalyze`

this enables readline, since read is shell builtin use `help read` to check its manpage :)

Comment: This enables readline but unfortunately doesn't support custom completions. I asked Chet to allow custom completion for this but he is yet to respond. Anyone wanting this feature enabled, please email a request to bug-bash@gnu.org.